How to set bolt connection.recv_timeout_seconds hints in metadata
I am using Neo4j 5.10 community edition as a graph computing engine.
There are series of datasets are used for some graph algorithm. The size of the graph is different but mainly more than 1 million nodes and several million relationships.
So when I use JavaScript client driver and gds.graph.project.cypher to create a graph in memory, sometimes it works and sometimes the process may go beyond 120s and I will get message like "Failed to connect to server. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: Connection lost. Server didn't respond in 120000ms".
First, I looked into the Neo4j server and client configures to find out if there is a configure option to change the timeout setting. And I tried transaction timeout but it did not work.
Then I looked into the the driver's source code and search for the error message, then I found that the error is caused by the setting of receiveTimeout.
And then I found that the receiveTimeout is set due to the server response metadata in here and I found that there is indeed a document about the bolt hint metadata but I can not find any docs about how to change it from server side or client side.
Luckily that I searched and found that there is a piece of description about the hint in go driver source code which says that "Since 4.3, this setting competes with connection read timeout hints, if the server-side option called "dbms.connector.bolt.connection_keep_alive_for_requests" is enabled."
So I restart the server with dbms.connector.bolt.connection_keep_alive_for_requests set to OFF and now it works fine and the error never occurred.
Although I got a work around, I still got confused about:

How to change the connection.recv_timeout_seconds hints in metadata in server configuration?
Actually I found that there is a setting called server.bolt.connection_keep_alive_streaming_scheduling_interval and the default value is 1m. But it seems that this keep alive interval does not work in this situation and my client timeout in 120s.

